# Keycloak with Identity Provider(OIDC)

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have 2 questions:

1. I'm using **Keycloak** identity provider function and I've integrated Keycloak to **UAE Pass** app, It's working). Keycloak requests to userinfo URL(sets UAE Pass token to header) and Keycloak has caught user's info and saves the info and generates Keycloak token. I should catch the UAE Pass token and set it to Keycloak token's claim. But I can't(.
   [image]
   What should I do?
2. There are username field(input), password field(input) and UAE Pass button(identity provider) in my keycloak login page. I should authenticating with UAE Pass with Postman(Rest API). I can get token with username and password but I can't send request to authenticating with UAE Pass.
   [image]
   What should I do?

Thanks for attention)

1. I've tried to attach UAE Pass token into Keycloak token with Identity Provider mappers. But mappers cannot catch value from previous response body or userinfo URL header(current request).
2. I've researched, but found olny getting token with username, password with Rest API